# How to send multiple parameter value in crystal report in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

how can i send multiple parameter value for crystal report using `asp.net` `C#`  But not display records on Page

```
protected void FillOrderByDrivers(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate, int ShowDriver, int SigDate)
        {
            DateTime DriverFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDriverFrom.Text);
            DateTime DriverTo = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDriverTo.Text);
            int DriverSegnification = int.Parse(ddlDriverSignificantDate.SelectedValue.ToString());
            int Driver = int.Parse(ddlDrivers.SelectedValue.ToString());

            int CompanyId = int.Parse(ddlComapny.SelectedValue.ToString());

            if(reportDocument == null)
                reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

    reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/OrdersByDrivers.rpt"));
            reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID, myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password, myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName, myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName);

            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@DateFrom", DriverFrom);
            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@DateTo", DriverTo);
            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@CompanyID", CompanyId);
            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@ShowDriversUsing", DriverSegnification);
            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@SigDate", Driver);


            //reportDocument.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
            rptClients.Visible = true;
            rptClients.ReportSource = reportDocument;
            rptClients.DataBind();
            rptClients.RefreshReport();

        }
```

Any suggestion will welcome Where i am wrong . Thanks

i have show the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145044/passing-multiple-parameter-to-crystal-report-in-asp-net) of stackoverflow but

Comment: are u sure that your crystal report is running fine independently ?

Comment: yes in my crystal report i pass parameter if i will not supply then how can this will display ? is any idea

Comment: So you have no problem with crystal report, the problem is in passing parameters through c# right?

Comment: yes , in upper section i pass the parameter in code is that correct ?

Comment: can you review the code is that correct or i am doing mistake in the code

Comment: thanks i will try that in my code . i am waiting

Comment: There is a correction in your code dude ! Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope u need to use following code for passing values to stored procedure, and your code is for passing values to crystal reports parameter. Try using the following code.

In Button Click use the following !

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter();

ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetResultdriver", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DATATYPE, LENGTH, "From"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DATATYPE, LENGTH, "To"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.DATATYPE, LENGTH, "Location"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ShowDriversUsing", SqlDbType.DATATYPE, LENGTH, "Location"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SigDate", SqlDbType.DATATYPE, LENGTH, "Location"));

cmd.Parameters[0].Value = dtpFrom.Text;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = dtpTo.Text;
cmd.Parameters[2].Value = cbCityCode.Text;
cmd.Parameters[3].Value = dtpTo.Text;
cmd.Parameters[4].Value = cbCityCode.Text;

conInfo.DatabaseName = "db name";
conInfo.UserID = "user id";
conInfo.Password = "password";
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

report.Load("report path");
SetDBLogonForReport(conInfo, report);
crvReports.ReportSource = report;
crvReports.Refresh();
```

Use the following code for Login Informations

```
private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo conInfo, ReportDocument report)
    {
        Tables tables = report.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = conInfo;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
        }
    }
```

Try this !!

Comment: Hi Hariharan thzx for your code but when i remove `@` from code i get error " Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)) "

Comment: are u passing the values to Crystal Reports Parameter or for Stored Procedures Parameter ??

Comment: in my Crystal report five parameter value is define where i pass the value from my parameter . `@DateFrom` , `@DateTo`, `@CompanyID`, `@ShowDriversUsing`,  `@SigDate` i passing the value direct .

Comment: ok then, give me some time dude ! I could resolve your prob !!

Comment: one more question in my mind is i need to first get the value form store procedure in dataset and after that pass the value for crystal report Parameters this geting me confuse because crystal report Databasefield is my storeprocedure named 'spGetResultdriver'

Comment: Clear !! then you need to pass values to your **Stored Procedures Parameter**. I will get you the right codes now !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23756/discussion-between-a-goutam-and-hariharan-anbazhagan)